# My computer crashed, are video games to blame?

Tags: windows-8.1, video, crash, gaming

I recently downloaded XCOM 2. I noticed whenever I played, after 10 minutes or so the fan would be going crazy,  I guess due to overheating. This was never an issue in the year I have been using this rig (I built it myself), it is usually a quiet computer. After a few days of gaming, my computer crashed and I had to re-install Windows.

Since I am not knowledgeable in this field, I am hoping some of you guys could help. I reinstalled the game and took CPU readings while playing (and the fan was going nuts). Are these readings high, and if so, what should I do to make sure my computer doesn't crash again?

[image]

Some specs:

- SAPPHIRE DUAL-X 100373L Radeon R9 280 3GB 384-Bit
- AMD A10-6800K APU with Radeon HD Graphics Processor 4.10 GHz
- XFX 550W TS Series 80+ Bronze Single Rail ATX 12V 44A 24PIN ATX Power Supply
- Cooler Master N200 mATX / mITX Tower Case Black
- Gigabyte F2A88XM-D3H mATX FM2+ A88X DDR3 2PCI-E16 PCI-E1 PCI CrossFire SATA3 HDMI USB3 Motherboard
- 16 GB of RAM

Also I didn't use thermal paste when building it. Maybe that is the culprit?

Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: You didnt use thermal paste on the CPU?

Comment: "I didn't use thermal paste when building it. " - Since you are not using a water cooler, this is the entire problem, it has nothing to do with the programs your running.  How you made it a year without thermal paste confuses the heck out of me. You having to reinstall Windows, was an unrealted problem, to the overheating problem.

Answer (score 4):

The problem looks clear from the screenshot. If the readings are correct, you have a CPU thermal transfer problem.
The core temp (package) is extremely high (100) compared to CPU socket temp (43), which means that you need to remove the heat-sink, clean it up and add thermal paste, because the heat no longer transfers well from CPU to heat-sink.

Also, please use GPU-Z to get a T reading from the video card sensor.

Answer (score 1):

Your temperatures are **extremely high.** Your computer is crashing as the CPU is so hot it is automatically shutting down to prevent hardware failure.

You need to apply thermal paste (properly) **now**! Once you do so the temperatures should fall back to safe temperatures, and your PC will be quieter.

Comment: I agree. Whenever building a PC, thermal paste is an absolute must. Not using it could risk damaging your CPU!